# Downloaded attachments from Enterprise vault are 0kb in size with only '@' as their name

Tags: vba, outlook

```vb
Sub Merge_daily_emails1()

    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Atch As Object
    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim filteredItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim itm As Object
    Dim strFilter As String

    strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%Daily Reports%'"
    Set filteredItems = myInbox.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    AttachmentPath = "H:\"
    If filteredItems.count > 0 Then
        For Each itm In filteredItems
            If itm.Attachments.count <> 0 Then
                For Each Atch In itm.Attachments
                    Atch.SaveAsFile AttachmentPath & Atch.Filename
                    Exit For
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "Does not Have an Attachment"
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set myOlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am trying to download all the attachments from my inbox email which contain the words "daily Report" in their subject line.

Some Excel files that I download come out to be **0kb in size** and have their name as **"@"**.

My best guess is that because these emails are old and opened using **enterprise vault** system, I am not able to download the files in a proper way.

Edit (ddate as Date) argument was the start date I was using for search and I have removed the code to make it simpler, now it will be searching the entire inbox.

Comment: Does the code run? `(ddate As Date)`

Comment: @Om3r Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the code and it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You may wana remove `(ddate As Date)` from your sub and declared `AttachmentPath` to `Dim attachmentPath As String` also Setting Option Explicit to Off is generally not a good practice

See MSDN on [Option Explicit Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)

Comment: I am able to download the files from the recent emails in my Inbox, it's just the emails which are old and using the enterprise value is where I get the attachments name as '@'.